# Can the state of removed Programs be recovered after they failed to pay rent?

Tags: solana-program, program, rent, state

From the [docs](https://docs.solana.com/developing/intro/rent) on rent:

> Accounts that do not maintain their rent exempt status, or have a balance high enough to pay rent, are removed from the network in a process known as garbage collection.

What happens if a Program is removed but, at some point in the future, the developer would like to recover both the Program and the state that it had contained? Does Solana offer any recovery mechanism?

For context: my background is in Ethereum, where most state rent proposals (e.g. [EIP-1682](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1682)) have incorporated an account recovery mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, its not possible to create new accounts that are not considered "rent-exempt". In other words, programs would stay on-chain unless the upgrade authority of the program explicitly closed the program.

https://docs.solana.com/developing/intro/rent#rent-exempt

> At the time of writing this, new Accounts and Programs are required to
> be initialized with enough LAMPORTS to become rent-exempt.

Comment: That's only at initialization time. What happens if the Program is not topped up with sufficient SOL, and the balance falls below the 2-year threshold?

Comment: It wouldn't need to be topped off because it was initialized with the amount of SOL required for the account to be "rent-exempt", meaning SOL is not deducted from the account. "rent" is bit of an outdated term, think of it more like a deposit for storing data on-chain, which can be fully refunded when an account is explicitly closed.

Comment: Ooh, I see. I'm getting it now. But what happens when the Program withdraws SOL in such a way that the resultant balance ends up less than the 2-year deposit requirement?